# Build for ios from ionic command failed

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I got this error when i ran

```
 ionic cordova run ios --device 


 65%] PreflightingApplication
2019-06-24 14:28:21.032 ios-deploy[7890:179934] [ !! ] Error 0xe800007e: The device OS version is too low. AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication(0, device, url, options, install_callback, 0)
ios-deploy: Command failed with exit code 253
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova run ios --device exited with exit code 253.
```

My

output for xcodebuild -showsdks
i

```
OS SDKs:
    iOS 11.2                        -sdk iphoneos11.2

iOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - iOS 11.2            -sdk iphonesimulator11.2

macOS SDKs:
    macOS 10.13                     -sdk macosx10.13

tvOS SDKs:
    tvOS 11.2                       -sdk appletvos11.2

tvOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - tvOS 11.2           -sdk appletvsimulator11.2

watchOS SDKs:
    watchOS 4.2                     -sdk watchos4.2

watchOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - watchOS 4.2         -sdk watchsimulator4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding the deployment target? Try adding to your `config.xml`:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="deployment-target" value="11.2" />
</platform>
```